# How do I return the first string from a list or a string itself if it was passed instead of a list?

Tags: python, splat

Ruby example of the mapping function I want:

```
["qwe", ["asd", "zxc"]].map{ |i| [*i][0] } => ["qwe", "asd"]

def f array_or_string
  [*array_or_string].first
end

["qwe", ["asd", "zxc"]].map &method(:f)    => ["qwe", "asd"]

f ["qwe", "zxc"]                           => "qwe"
f "asd"                                    => "asd"
```

Since strings are iterable in Python, how do I <s>fight this language design fail</s> achieve the same result elegantly?

```
def f(array_or_string):
    ???
```

Comment: why shouldnt a string be iterable? how are you qualified to deem it as a design fail?  care to put in plain english what your expected inputs and outputs are?

Comment: @SukriKalra Even if it is wrong, you should not edit the code except for reformatting, adjusting white characters or comments, etc.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, expected inputs and outputs are in the question title. The design fail is shown in a demostrating the Ruby code and a fact that I don't know, how to make it in Python with the same elegance.

Comment: @sawa, he did right edit.

Comment: You say that because *you* don't know how to do something in Python, *Python* has a design flaw?

Comment: thats a knowledge failure on your part not a design fail on python but meh ...

Comment: @user2357112, you are welcome to **make me know**.

Comment: You can use type detection or do you want another way?

Comment: Downvoting because I should never search for elegance in Python language?

Comment: @Nakilon they are downvoting you because you accidentally blamed python.  I'll fix your english for you

Comment: @Stephan, your edit was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(something):
    if isinstance(something,basestring): 
         return something
    elif isinstance(something,(list,tuple)):
         return something[0]
    raise Exception("Unknwon Something:%s <%s>"%(something,type(something)))
```

assuming I understand your question correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're really after is an equivalent of Ruby's "wrap it in an array if it isn't one" operator. Python doesn't deem this important enough to build it into the language syntax. You can define it yourself easily enough:

```
def tolist(thing):
    return thing if isinstance(thing, list) else [thing]

def first_or_only(thing):
    return tolist(thing)[0]
```

Comment: But Python does have the splat operator actually. And I don't understand why it is not same powerfull.

Comment: It does not work if thing is a tuple or another iterable though…

Comment: @septi: Indeed it won't. That's one of the reasons Python doesn't have this operator.